# Getting terminal window size in curses mainloop

Tags: python, terminal, resize, window, curses

I have a script, which I would like have printing current terminal window size every time it changes.

here's the sample of my code:

```
import curses

def main():
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    seq = 0
    while 1:
        stdscr.refresh()
        ch = stdscr.getch()
        seq += 1
        if ch == curses.KEY_RESIZE:
            stdscr.addstr(1, 0, ','.join(str(_) for _ in stdscr.getmaxyx())+' '+str(seq))                                                  
            stdscr.refresh()

    curses.endwin()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The issue with it is that stdscr.getmaxyx() always returns same values though getch() gets KEY_RESIZE successfully.
Thanks.

### Update

Turned out, the problem was with the linux mint ncurses library, everything works fine on debian and all the rpm-based distros i've checked. Probably, this applies to ubuntu and it's other derivatives too.

Comment: What OS / terminal are you using?  The code works as expected using PuTTY connected to a Linux (Fedora) box.

Comment: ubuntu with terminator/gnome terminal/xterm don't want to work. I should probably try with others.

Comment: Strange, just tried it with other ubuntu box, and it works. Interesting.

Comment: I'm wrong though, works on Debian Wheezy, and does not work on Linux Mint 17

Comment: Works on ubuntu 14.04 in gnome terminal using python 3

Comment: Have you tried resetting stdscr with your own sigwinch handler as per [this advice](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/609520-curses-resizing-windows)?